# Windows batch file - ipconfig / skype

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want that Skype only starts when I am connected on a specific LAN IP address.

```
@echo off
set ip_address_string="IPv4 Address"
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:%ip_address_string%`) do echo bounded IP-address: %%f
```

But how can I realize that Skype only will be called if any ip address contains 64.2.4.*?

Moreover, the batch file will run every 5 minutes and if it is required the Skype-process should be killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "ip_address_string=64.2.4."

ipconfig | findstr /c:"%ip_address_string%" >nul|| (
    echo IP "%ip_address_string%" not found.
     taskkill /im skype.exe /f
    exit /b 0
)
echo connected as/to  "%ip_address_string%"
```

?